# Prevent Google from indexing images

Tags: search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, google-index

I have a site where all my images are stored in a specific folder, for example `/images/984728176386375837629856e.png` but I don't want this page to appear on the SERP. Can I disable the indexing of the `image` folder with `robots.txt`?

Answer (score 4):

From the [Google Search Console help docs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en):

> If you want Google to exclude the `image-name-here.png` that appears
>   on your site at `www.example.com/images/image-name-here.png`, add the
>   following to your robots.txt file:
>
> ```
> User-agent: Googlebot-Image 
> Disallow: /images/image-name-here.png
> ```
>
> The next time Google crawls your site, it will see this directive and
>   drop your image from the search results.
>
> To remove all the images on your site from being indexed, add the
>   following to the robots.txt file in your server root:
>
> ```
> User-agent: Googlebot-Image 
> Disallow: /
> ```
>
> Additionally, Google has introduced increased flexibility to the
>   robots.txt file standard through the use of asterisks. Disallow
>   patterns may include "*" to match any sequence of characters, and
>   patterns may end in "$" to indicate the end of a name.
>
> To remove all files of a specific file type (for example, to include
>   .jpg but not .png images), you'd use the following robots.txt entry:
>
> ```
> User-agent: Googlebot-Image 
> Disallow: /*.gif$
> ```